# jade not rendering specific elements, i am using angular $sanitize

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, pug, mean-stack

i am developing a mean web app
but jade is not rendering specific elements like text boxes and text area

this the jade code

```
.row
    // left column
    .col-md-6
        .box.box-primary
            .box-header.with-border
                h3.box-title Bus Info
            // /.box-header
            // form start

            form(role='form')
                .box-body
                    .form-group
                        label Bus/Route Number:
                        input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Enter ...')
                    .form-group
                        label Route (enter stops separated by commas)
                        textarea.form-control(placeholder='Enter ...', rows='3')
                    .form-group
                        label Driver Name
                        input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Enter ...')
                    .form-group
                        label Driver Phone
                        input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Enter ...')
                    h4 Driver Login Credentials
                    .form-group
                        label Bus ID
                        input.form-control(type='text', disabled='', placeholder='BA1002')
                    .form-group
                        label(for='exampleInputPassword1') PIN (used for driver login)
                        input#exampleInputPassword1.form-control(type='password', placeholder='Password')
                    .form-group
                        label(for='exampleInputPassword1') Confirm PIN
                        input#exampleInputPassword1.form-control(type='password', placeholder='Password')
                // /.box-body
                .box-footer
                    button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Add Bus
        // /.box
```

this is the result

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="box box-primary">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Bus Info</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Bus/Route Number:</label>
        </div><div class="form-group">
        <label>Route (enter stops separated by commas)</label>
      </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Driver Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Driver Phone</label>
        </div>
        <h4>Driver Login Credentials</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Bus ID</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>PIN (used for driver login)</label>
        </div><div class="form-group">
        <label>Confirm PIN</label>
      </div></div>
      <div class="box-footer">Add Bus</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is the html result here  all the textboxes and text area are missing...
i think sanitize is eliminating all the input elements..
how to allow those input elements?
thank you.
any kind of help is always appreciated.

Comment: By the way i got the solution

it was bcoz ngsanitize was removing all the input elements from the html...

i solved this problem by disabling Strict Contextual Escaping

see this link for more

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

see the section "Can I disable SCE completely?"

Answer (score 0):

With your .jade file:

```
.row
// left column
.col-md-6
    .box.box-primary
        .box-header.with-border
            h3.box-title Bus Info
        // /.box-header
        // form start

        form(role='form')
            .box-body
                .form-group
                    label Bus/Route Number:
                    input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Enter ...')
                .form-group
                    label Route (enter stops separated by commas)
                    textarea.form-control(placeholder='Enter ...', rows='3')
                .form-group
                    label Driver Name
                    input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Enter ...')
                .form-group
                    label Driver Phone
                    input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Enter ...')
                h4 Driver Login Credentials
                .form-group
                    label Bus ID
                    input.form-control(type='text', disabled='', placeholder='BA1002')
                .form-group
                    label(for='exampleInputPassword1') PIN (used for driver login)
                    input#exampleInputPassword1.form-control(type='password', placeholder='Password')
                .form-group
                    label(for='exampleInputPassword1') Confirm PIN
                    input#exampleInputPassword1.form-control(type='password', placeholder='Password')
            // /.box-body
            .box-footer
                button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Add Bus
    // /.box
```

in html It is this below:

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- left column-->
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Bus Info</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header-->
            <!-- form start-->
            <form role="form">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Bus/Route Number:</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter ..." class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Route (enter stops separated by commas)</label>
                        <textarea placeholder="Enter ..." rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Driver Name</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter ..." class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Driver Phone</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter ..." class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Driver Login Credentials</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Bus ID</label>
                        <input type="text" disabled="" placeholder="BA1002" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">PIN (used for driver login)</label>
                        <input id="exampleInputPassword1" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Confirm PIN</label>
                        <input id="exampleInputPassword1" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body-->
                <div class="box-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Bus</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope It'll help your problem.

And I changed your code (html) to jade as below:

```
html
body
    .row
        .col-md-6
            .box.box-primary
                .box-header.with-border
                    h3.box-title Bus Info
                .box-body
                    .row
                        .form-group // You need to understand, each row is 12 columns
                            .row-md-2
                                label Bus/Route Number:
                            .row-md-4
                                .input.form-control(class=''..) // input you put here
                    .row
                        .form-group
                        ...
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.... i got the answer
ng sanitize was removing all the input elements and functions.
i solved this problem by putting 

$sceProvider.enabled(false);

in the code thus i disabled the contextual escape.....
now it is working....

by the way have you tested your code, i think it wont work..

Answer (score 0):

By the way i got the solution

it was bcoz ngsanitize was removing all the input elements from the html...

i solved this problem by disabling Strict Contextual Escaping

see this link for more

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

see the section "Can I disable SCE completely?"